# How to toggle (show/hide) Tooltip?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying to force show a tooltip when a method is `true`, how can I achieve this?

The process is described in the Tooltip [overview](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview#showing-and-hiding) and [API](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api) but I can't find an example of its implementation.

I would like to be able to show a warning, using the tooltip, if a user tried to input something into a text input field.

- Angular 4
- Material 2.0.0-beta.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to manually show a tooltip you can use `@ViewChild`. Here's an example:
**HTML**
`<div #tooltip mdTooltip="I'm a tooltip!">`

**TS**
@ViewChild(MdTooltip) tooltip: MdTooltip;

```
showTooltip() {
  this.tooltip.show(0)
}
```

If you want to show a tooltip every time user focues on an input just insert `mdTooltip` directive on `md-form-field` or `input` element.